# Arduino-cli in package

Tags: dpkg, arduino

I create a dpkg and in the post install script, I want to use arduino-cli.
In root, user, the arduino-cli send me the list of available connected device.
But in the dpkg's execution, the command send me an empty string.

Here is the code I use in the postinst file:

```
....
echo '///////////////////////////////////////'
echo 'Install arduino binary file'
data=`sudo -u pi arduino-cli board list`
echo 'hihi' $data
data2=`sudo -u root arduino-cli board list  | awk  '{print $1, $6};'`
echo 'hihi2' $data2
data3=`sudo  arduino-cli board list  | awk  '{print $1, $6};'`
echo 'hihi3' $data3
...
```

The result :

```
hihi
hihi2
hihi3
```

what  happens in the dpkg ? Is it a owner problem?

Edit: Here is a list of command I tried

```
echo arduino-cli board list 
arduino-cli board list                      ###OK
data00=arduino-cli board list     
echo 'hihi00' $data00                       ###empty
data0=`arduino-cli board list`
echo 'hihi0' $data0                         ###empty
data1=`sudo -u pi arduino-cli board list`  
echo 'hihi' $data1                          ###empty
data2=`sudo -u root arduino-cli board list  | awk  '{print $1, $6};'`
echo 'hihi2' $data2                         ###empty
data3=`sudo  arduino-cli board list  | awk  '{print $1, $6};'`
echo 'hihi3' $data3                         ###empty
```

Comment: you can't enter sudo password while running the script. But postinst scripts are run as `root` anyways, so just remove the `sudo` from your script and see if it works

Comment: I have the same trouble without sudo. I try to execute the command as root (with su), the command sends me the list properly.

Comment: It seems that the pipe don't work in dpkg. I want to extract a data from my command response. Is there another way to process it ?

Comment: seems like the issue is the variable, not the command. otherwise `data00` should have printed *something*, since its value was never actually executed. Is this `bash` or `sh`? can you assign a string to the variable and see if it prints it?